# How to check the size of a docker image without pulling it?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I was at the docker hub looking for a python 3.6 image. There are many options available. In my case, I was looking for an image that, once built, would be less than 150 MB. Is there a way to find out about its size before pulling it? i.e. before running docker pull python:3.6-alpine

[UPDATE] I took at look at here as suggested in the commments https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=1&name=3.6-alpine

[image]

it is not clear to me what these rows and compressed sizes next to it represent. I thought they may be the architecture layers and that adding them all would give me the total size (which is 96.6MB)but none of this seems to hold, even the numbers under digest are different.

[image]

Comment: Not from the CLI but it's available in docker-hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags

Comment: Very interesting? How should the different sizes indicated under a tag (e.g. 3.6-alpine3.11) be interpreted?

Comment: Size of download, I think, given that the site mentions that it's the compressed size. Keep in mind docker images can share FS layers so actual download size / size on disk might be lower.

Comment: I tried it out for alpine 3.6-alpine3.11 and once downloaded the images is 94.6MB which does not correspond to the added layers so still a bit confused.